# Trouble implementing shadows in WebGL

Tags: webgl, shadow

I am trying to implement shadows into my WEBGL 2.0 Project using this tutorial
https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shadows.html
Currently I am getting really bad results like this:
[image]

Basically a ton of the terrain is being drawn in shadow that shouldn't be. The light projection is from your camera towards the direction you are looking so hypothetically you shouldn't be able to see any shdaows becuase the light projection is the same as your camera ( I am just doing this for testing until I can get this working properly)

I have everything the same as the tutorial I believe except I am using glMatrix instead of their matrix math library (shouldn't matter I would assume).  Here's the thing though. I don't use a model view matrix for anything I am rendering so none of my points are on a -1,1 range. They can go out as far as -3200...ect    Its just all one big terrain mesh chunked out.
I think the issue lies with how I am creating the texture matrix

```
textureMatrix = glMatrix.mat4.create();

glMatrix.mat4.translate(textureMatrix,textureMatrix,[0.5,0.5,0.5]);
glMatrix.mat4.scale(textureMatrix,textureMatrix,[0.5,0.5,0.5]);
glMatrix.mat4.multiply(textureMatrix,textureMatrix, projectionMatrix);

glMatrix.mat4.invert(lightMatrix,lightMatrix);
glMatrix.mat4.multiply(textureMatrix,textureMatrix, lightMatrix);
```

I am using the same matrix for the light projection as your normal projection, is that an issue? if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because the Y position of your light (in your example, it is much more the distance between the eye and the scene) is too big for the Z size of your shadow volume (the size of your shadow volume in the view direction.) Here if posY is inside the wireframe box :
[image]

But if you increase posY too much (i.e. your shapes get out of the shadow volume, they disappear
[image]

So you should increase the size of your shadow volume (or shrinken your scene, either way.) You cannot simulate that with the slider because they just give you the control to the two dimensions X and Y dimensions : projWidth and projHeight.

i.e. in the last code in your tutorial page, the latest parameter ("far") for example change it from 10 to 100

```
const lightProjectionMatrix = settings.perspective
    ? m4.perspective(
        degToRad(settings.fieldOfView),
        settings.projWidth / settings.projHeight,
        0.5,  // near
        10)   // far
    : m4.orthographic(
        -settings.projWidth / 2,   // left
         settings.projWidth / 2,   // right
        -settings.projHeight / 2,  // bottom
         settings.projHeight / 2,  // top
         0.5,                      // near
         100);                      // far
```

Then you can increase posY far more :

[image]

without having your full code, it is hard to reproduce and help you. Could you not try to just inject your scene into the tutorial code ? You can bind the viewpoint with the source and orientation of the light by using the same inputs : (just adding 0.5 to X to see a bit of shadow and make sure it is properly computed.)

```
/*const cameraPosition = [settings.cameraX, settings.cameraY, 15];*/
const cameraPosition = [settings.posX+0.5, settings.posY, settings.posZ];
/*const target = [0, 0, 0]; */ 
const target = [settings.targetX, settings.targetY, settings.targetZ];
```

[image]

Comment: Do I shrink it by scaling the lightProjectionMatrix ?

Comment: indeed. I edited my answer to illustrate in the tutorial last example

Comment: If I am using a perspective camera for the light, does that mean I only have the aspect ratio to do the scaling?

Comment: it (the "far" parameter) works the same for a perspective camera. I am not sure to get the link with the scaling ?

Comment: I have the zfar on both matrixes really far out and it doesn't make a difference. I think something is wrong with my math

Comment: without having your full code, it is hard to reproduce and help you. Could you not try to just inject your scene into the tutorial code ? I could bind the viewpoint with the source and orientation of the light by using the same inputs : (just adding 0.5 to X to see a bit of shadow and make sure it is properly computed.)     /*const cameraPosition = [settings.cameraX, settings.cameraY, 15];*/
    const cameraPosition = [settings.posX+0.5, settings.posY, settings.posZ];
    /*const target = [0, 0, 0]; */
    const target = [settings.targetX, settings.targetY, settings.targetZ];

Comment: You are right, I need to just do that. I was trying not to post my code because I am implementing it on top of a pre-existing project and it would be a mess to go through for someone. Thanks for your help.